# Correct Doctype with Semantic Ui Sidebar - different browsers

Tags: jquery, html, pagepiling.js

I've created a simple html business presentation page, nothing special with pagePiling.js and for sidebar i chose semantic-ui-sidebar.

Everything works fine in different browsers with different doctypes. I don't know what to change. If i leave the doctype chrome will display everything correctly. But Mozilla Firefox needs doctype so that jquery will return the right window.size. When i set , the sidebar stops working.

1. Problem: Without doctype everything works, but firefox doesnt execute jquery command window.height() correct.
2. Problem: With Doctype html mozilla works correct but the sidebar plugin stops working correctly.

Following the html construct with deleted content. Somebody help please?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>pagePiling.js plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/pagePiling.js-master/jquery.pagepiling.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/jquery.pagepiling.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://studentcouch.de/sidebar.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://studentcouch.de/sidebar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*
                * Plugin intialization
                */
                $('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
                menu: '#menu',
                anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page6', 'page7', 'page8'],
                sectionsColor: ['white', '#ee005a', '#2C3E50', '#39C'],
                navigation: {
                'position': 'right',
                'tooltips': ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3', 'Page 4', 'Page 5', 'Page 6', 'Page 7', 'Page 8']
                },
                afterRender: function(){
                    $('#pp-nav').addClass('custom');
                    },
                    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                        if(index>1){
                            $('#pp-nav').removeClass('custom');
                        }else{
                            $('#pp-nav').addClass('custom');
                        }
                    }
                });
                /*
                * Internal use of the demo website
                */
                $('#showExamples').click(function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#examplesList').toggle();
                });
                $("#page5image").height($(window).height()*0.7);
                $('html').click(function(){
                    $('#examplesList').hide();
                });
                $('.sidebartoggle').click(function() {
                    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('show');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .sidebartoggle {

            }
            /* Section 1
            * --------------------------------------- */
            }
            /* Overwriting fullPage.js tooltip color
            * --------------------------------------- */
            #pp-nav.custom .pp-tooltip{
            color: #AAA;
            }
            #markup{
            display: block;
            width: 450px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            text-align: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui right vertical sidebar">
            <ul class="navside">
                <li> <a href="/">Support</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/">Team</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/">Jobs</a></li>
                <li> <a href="/">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pusher">
            <div style="background-color:white" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header"><img src="" style="height:50px"/></div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Login </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Registrierung</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li data-menuanchor="page1"><a href="#page1">Käufer</a></li>
                        <li data-menuanchor="page2"> <a href="#page2">Händler</a></li>
                        <li data-menuanchor="page3"> <a href="#page3">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="sidebartoggle">Menü</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="pagepiling">
                <div id="section1" class="section">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                                <h1>Side one</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="section">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h1> side two </h1>
                                <img id="page5image" class="center" src="http://studentcouch.de/device_page5.png" style="display:block;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a way to reproduce the problem. We don't know what `sidebar.js` does... Try to reproduce it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/418/).

Comment: validating your HTML ends up with: Line 120, Column 14: Stray end tag div. Get rid of that and check again please

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/590/ / Im using pagePiling.js and semantic-ui-sidebar. In the fiddle the semantic ui sidebar doesn't work, i don't know why. Locally without doctype everthing works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Looking closer, this is due to the bootstrap stylesheet conflicting with the sidebar stylesheet. I found this out by removing bootstrap css and then it works with the proper html5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without spending a lot more time (than i've already spent :)) it is best to make a minimal case example without bootstrap elements, just divs and some text and build it up. Try adding the bootstrap file in bit by bit and find out where the conflict is then override what is in the bootstrap file so they work in harmony.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! I will do that and when i find the problem, i will post the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No probs :) plz mark it as the correct answer if you think this is and are able to. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a validation issue. Looks like you have an extra close div tag on the end of your HTML. When you have issues like that in future, always worth validating the HTML. Let me know if that fixes your issues.

Comment: that fixes nothing :/